# create a new column that compares rows in another column if it's different plus 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column named Customer and trying to create a new column Line ID, where it starts from 1 and increase by one whenever the customer is different from the previous customer. I'm using pandas dataframe.

example:

```
   Customer    | Line ID
    Pepsi      |    1
    Pepsi      |    1
    Lego       |    2
    Mcdonald's |    3
    Mcdonald's |    3
```

I can use a for loop for this but is there an easier way? I would like to keep the code short but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Maybe `df['Line ID'] = df.groupby('Customer', sort=False).ngroup() + 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the previous row to the current which give you a boolean mask the apply cumulative sum:

```
df['Line ID'] = df['Customer'].ne(df['Customer'].shift()).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
     Customer  Line ID
0       Pepsi        1
1       Pepsi        1
2        Lego        2
3  Mcdonald's        3
4  Mcdonald's        3
```

Detail about the mask:

```
>>> df['Customer'].ne(df['Customer'].shift())
0     True  # New group
1    False
2     True  # New group
3     True  # New group
4    False
Name: Customer, dtype: bool
```